# php поменять точку на запятую

Tags: php

Обрабатываю числа функцией `round`:

```
$kolall_itog = round(($kolall_itog + $kolall), 2);
```

Кодировка страницы utf-8. Как при выводе подменить точку на запятую?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo number_format($kolall_itog, 2, ',', '');
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php